# Unity WebGL using WebAssembly Streaming

Tags: webassembly, unity-webgl

I'm trying to use webassembly streaming feature but it does not work.
I did follow the unity docs instruction of Server configuration for WebAssembly streaming.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/Webgl-Server-configuration-for-WebAssembly-streaming.html

I'm using Unity 2019.2.20f1

In Unity player settings, I set the compression format as gzip and enabled WebAssembly streaming.

I added .htaccess file into the Build folder.
following is the contents of the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddEncoding gzip .unityweb
  AddType application/wasm .wasm
  AddEncoding gzip .wasm
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
</IfModule>
```

and I also added

```
application/wasm    wasm
```

to /etc/mime.type

But I'm getting this Error.

```
wasm streaming compile failed: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 1f 8b 08 18 @+0
```

I did restart the service after setting up the needed modifications.

my webgl builds work perfectly without webassembly streaming feature.
Is there anyone who knows about this problem and what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I solved this one.

first you need to enable the AllowOverride in httpd.conf file to use .htaccess file.
in my case it's located at /etc/httpd/conf
and open the httpd.conf file using `vi httpd.conf` command
and find .htaccess using `/.htaccess` command

there will be `<Directory "/var/www">` and `<Directory "/var/www/html">`
and you will see for both of them AllowOverrides are set as None.
You need to change those to All.

simply hit `i` and you will be in insert mode, change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
make sure you change both `/var/www` and `/var/www/html`
When you're done, hit `ESC` and type `:wq` to save the modification and exit.

following .htaccess file does not work.

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddEncoding gzip .unityweb
  AddType application/wasm .wasm
  AddEncoding gzip .wasm
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
</IfModule>
```

change .htaccess file as following will do the job.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
<Files "*.wasm">
    AddType application/wasm .wasm
    AddEncoding gzip wasm
</Files>
<Files "*.unityweb">
    AddEncoding gzip unityweb
</Files>
```

If you're using brotli, change `gzip` to `br`
Lastly, you have to restart httpd service by using `service httpd restart` command.
Boom! It works now.

And about the load speed i mean,  sure it's faster than the non-WebAssembly Streaming.
but my project has total of 50mb of data size and the difference was minimal.
So if you're project has big amount of data to load, you should give it a try.
but if it's not that big, don't expect sth dramatic here.